# Loading data from excel or .csv into Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, data-analysis

just wanted to clarify something real quick: I have searched the internet for dozens of approaches on how to load data from a .csv file or excel file into python, but none of the seem to work for me as I usually get the error, that the file I want to load doesn't exist, but I know that they do and they are on my computer or on my iCloud. Does it matter if they are in the Cloud? How do i solve this problem?

What I have tried:

From python.org directly:

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Lets say I want to import the data from [gr3b](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n1pmsoj1xar68uz/gr3b.csv?dl=0) (this is my actual data file, I recommend to open it in a text editor, otherwise it can f*ck up the commas sometimes). How do I do that? The path should be "/Users/myusername/Documents/Universität /4.Semester/PC2 Praktikum/Experiment A54 Data/gr3b.csv"

Please help me, its getting really out of hand to manually type in all data sets I get.
Thank you!

Comment: You are probably in the wrong directory when calling your script.

Comment: print the value of reader variable and check what you are getting, if it is none then u must be in wrong directory.

Comment: @DeepakUmredkar how do I do that? I have no idea what you are talking about. I tried the answer in the supposedly identical post and what I get is again an error "Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 3"

Comment: Import os and sys, this way you can set your working folder. As if the .py file is save in this folder.
Now, since your working from this folder it will detect the file! try this:
since you can't use enters in comments:
   `import csv<enter>`
    `import os ,sys<enter>`
    `os.chdir("C:/Users/myusername/Documents/Universität /4.Semester/PC2 Praktikum/Experiment A54 Data")<enter>`
    
    `with open('gr3b.csv') as f:<enter>`
       `reader = csv.reader(f)<enter>`
       `for i in reader:<enter>`
           `print(i)<enter>`

Comment: @DevOps ok that works, thank you! but now I get a list that just looks like

     ['650', '00;0', '221351']

so the columns should be separated by a ; and the decimal separators are unfortunately ',' and not '.'
is there a way to change that?

Comment: You can try: `print(float(i))`